# 2012 Cluster service name failing

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2012

I have successfully created a cluster, but any services I try to cluster fail with the same or similar symptoms (I have tried clustering DTC and installing a SQL cluster).

Environment:

2 – nodes – both Windows Server 2012 – third 2012 box acting as an iSCSI SAN – all machines are on one Hyper-V host – Domain is Windows server 2003

2 networks – 10.x.x.x for the external, and 192.168.154.x for the internal & iSCSI – Windows Firewall is off

I cannot get either the DTC or SQL to work within the cluster – both seem to have the same issue – they appear to install OK, but the associated computer objects do not get created in AD, nor do DNS entries, then the network name resources fail with the following errors:

System Events:

> 1196 - Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed
>   registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) for the following
>   reason: The handle is invalid

(I have created DNS entries manually, but this has not helped)

> 1069 - Cluster resource 'MGCLSQLDEVDTC' of type 'Network Name' in
>   clustered role 'MGCLSQLDEVDTC' failed.
>
> 1205 - The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or
>   application 'MGCLSQLDEVDTC' completely online or offline. One or more
>   resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the availability
>   of the clustered service or application.
>
> 1254 - Clustered role 'MGCLSQLDEVDTC' has exceeded its failover
>   threshold.  It has exhausted the configured number of failover
>   attempts within the failover period of time allotted to it and will be
>   left in a failed state.  No additional attempts will be made to bring
>   the role online or fail it over to another node in the cluster. 
>   Please check the events associated with the failure.  After the issues
>   causing the failure are resolved the role can be brought online
>   manually or the cluster may attempt to bring it online again after the
>   restart delay period.
>
> 1228 - Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' encountered an
>   error enabling the network name on this node. The reason for the
>   failure was:   'Unable to obtain a logon token'.
>
> The error code was '1326'.

Security Events:

4625 - An account failed to log on Subject: Node server, Account for which logon failed: CNO

Some errors from the cluster log:

> 2050 - [RES] Network Name: [NNLIB] LogonUserEx fails for user
>   mgclsqldev$: 1326 (useSecondaryPassword: 0)
>
> 2050 - [RES] Network Name : Identity: Get Token Request,
>   currently doesnt have a token!
>
> 2050 - [RES] Network Name : AccountAD: Slow operation
>   has exception ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE(6)' because of
>   '::ImpersonateLoggedOnUser( GetToken() )'
>
> 2051 - [RES] Network Name : Online thread Failed:
>   ERROR_SUCCESS(0)' because of 'Initializing netname configuration for
>   MGCLSQLDEVDTC failed with error 6.'
>
> 2051 - [RHS] Online for resource MGCLSQLDEVDTC failed.
>
> 2050 - [RCM] HandleMonitorReply: ONLINERESOURCE for 'MGCLSQLDEVDTC',
>   gen(7) result 5018/0.
>
> 2051 - [RCM] rcm::RcmResource::HandleFailure: (MGCLSQLDEVDTC)

The cluster computer object ended up in the same OU as the cluster nodes which is different from the default “Computers” OU – I went in there and assigned all kinds of permissions, but that didn’t seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Windows Server 2012 - the same thing happens setting up a DAG for Exchange 2013.

Create the computer object manually *before* creating the cluster.

Comment: Thank you!  Please note that the computer object must be disabled after you create it - the cluster wizard will helpfully tell you this, but then it will get further, but still fail - it worked after I exited and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

Errr, definitely don't register the DNS addresses of your resources manually.  You need to ensure that there aren't any static records, both A and PTR.

Could you up the verbosity of your cluster logging and submit your cluster log file (or a portion thereof)?  There's more info in here than the event log.